# Creating a Motion Update in JavaFX with Java 8

Tags: java, timer, javafx, momentum

I had a simple JavaFX game where I moved the character with key codes. I now want to improve upon this and add some "momentum". But with my run method, the my character does not move. Please help. Here is my code with the previous method of moving the character commmented out.

Notes: I have global ints h and v set up. For the

```
new scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent. KEY_PRESSED, ( key) -> {
```

I imported the following:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

which I think is correct.

```
 scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent. KEY_PRESSED, ( key) -> {

            new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {   
                public void run() {
                    // Refreshes speed
                    if(h > -50 && h < 50)
                        iv2.setX( iv2.getX() + h);
                    if(v > -50 && v < 50)
                        iv2.setY( iv2.getY() + v);
                }
            }, 30, 30);

            if( key.getCode()==KeyCode. ENTER) {
                System. out.println( "You pressed enter");
            }
            if( key.getCode()==KeyCode. LEFT) {
                if( iv2.getX() - 25 > 0){
                    //iv2.setX( iv2.getX() - 50);
                    --h;
                }
            }
            if( key.getCode()==KeyCode. RIGHT) {
                if( iv2.getX() + 125 < scene.getWidth()){
                    //iv2.setX( iv2.getX() + 50);
                    ++h;
                }
            }
            if( key.getCode()==KeyCode. DOWN) {
                if( iv2.getY() + 150 < scene.getHeight()){
                    //iv2.setY( iv2.getY() + 50);
                    ++v;
                }
            }
            if( key.getCode()==KeyCode. UP) {
                if( iv2.getY() - 25 > 0)
                    //iv2.setY( iv2.getY() - 50);
                    --v;
            }

      });
```